# Sliding Up Panel hide by swipe down

Tags: android, swipe, bottom-sheet

[image]

This example from bottom sheet behavior. I am using [SlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) instead how to recreate last hide behavior  by swipe down using SlidingUpPanel library?